# Gcd and linear combination (backwards) program in java with steps

Tags: java

I have this gcd calculation using the euclidean law .. then I calculate the linear combination as it shown under ... I wrote a program the finds them but I have a problem with the second part how could I print the linear combination backwards as it shown under In java (I want to sum the Coefficient of the same number)

This is the output of the program

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BMUh.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)